# ListView and BaseAdapter implementation showing duplicate elements

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I have a ListView supported by my custom BaseAdapter implementation with a database behind it all. When I first insert an item into my database, everything is fine. However, when I add another item, my ListView suddenly displays 3 items instead of 2. If I add another item, the ListView updates and suddenly I see 5 items. When I hit the back button and go back to the previous activity and launch the ListView activity again, it shows the right number of items again. So either my ListView or my adapter isn't being updated correctly but I can't see where it's going wrong. I'd very much  appreciate some help.

My code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.goals_main_screen);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.goal_listview);
    customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.card_grid_item, gridArray);
    customGridAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(){
            retrieveCurrentGoals();
        }
    });
    mListView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            goToDetailedGoalView((int) id);
        }
    });
    retrieveCurrentGoals();
}

private void retrieveCurrentGoals(){
    String[] projection = {DatabaseHelper.KEY_ROWID, DatabaseHelper.KEY_GOAL_ID};
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_USER_GOALS, projection, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0; i<c.getCount();i++){
        String [] goalData = getGoalData(c.getInt(1));
        gridArray.add(goalData);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
}

private String[] getGoalData(int id){
    String[] projection = {DatabaseHelper.KEY_GOAL_TITLE, DatabaseHelper.KEY_GOAL_CATEGORY};
    String selection = "_id = " + id;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_GOALS, projection, selection, null, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        String[] data = {"", "", ""};
        data[0] = c.getString(0);
        data[1] = Integer.toString(c.getInt(1));
        data[2] = String.valueOf(id);
        return data;
    }
    c.close();
    return null;
}

private void goToDetailedGoalView(int id){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GoalCardDetail.class);
    i.putExtra(SharedData.GOAL_ID.getValue(), id);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}

public void toGoalSelectionScreen(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayCardActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i,GO_TO_GOAL_CARD_SCREEN);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == GO_TO_GOAL_CARD_SCREEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        System.out.println("ListView holds: " + mListView.getCount());
        customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing Array before adding new elements

```
  private void retrieveCurrentGoals(){
     gridArray.clear();
     String[] projection = {DatabaseHelper.KEY_ROWID, DatabaseHelper.KEY_GOAL_ID};
     Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_USER_GOALS, projection, null, null, null);
     c.moveToFirst();
     for(int i=0; i<c.getCount();i++){
       String [] goalData = getGoalData(c.getInt(1));
       gridArray.add(goalData);
       c.moveToNext();
     }
    c.close();
   }
```

As you said first time its retrieving perfectly but second time and on it starts giving duplicate values. This might be due to you are using class variable **gridArray**. Check first line in method which remove all element prior to adding new set of data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It happens because when you call `retrieveCurrentGoals()` you always read all rows in database and attach they to your `gridArray`.

Initially you have added first item, 
at second time you have added first and second 
and etc.

As one of possible solutions call `clear` method of you `arrayList` before set new data

Answer (score 0):

Does the `Cursor` in `getGoalData()` have expected length (previous length + 1) ?

I strongly recommend using `CursorLoader` class and implementing `LoaderCallbacks` in the `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean your array before adding the data in it. as  leave and again come to current activity or fragment will leads to adding  data each time in your array every time,thats is why  your are getting dublicate data.just clean your gridarray and goal data before you adding data to it.that's it.